# Anchor tag links not working in jquery pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jsfiddle.net/qdfET/1/
```

I want to do so when I click on help 1 link then it should go to content of C1 in popup window and same for help 2 link. But it's not working like that. I know it's small thing but it is working fine on same page but not in jquery popup.

Please advise for this.

Comment: can you make a fiddle,or share your jquery

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context... Or this is just a copy/paste error in your question

Comment: Anchors need end tag: `</a>`. `href` should be `#C1`.

Comment: </a> tag and href should be #c1 both don't help.

Comment: And what about <a href='#C1', as Curt has already mentioned?

Comment: I changed div id for both to <div id='container1' & <div id='container2', but it is not working.

Comment: hello, shijin... here is fiddle ...

http://jsfiddle.net/qdfET/

Answer (score 0):

firstly if you respect W3C, the id tag have to be unique as said by Curt,

I propose 2 solutions the first is to goto the right help block and the second is to show only the right help block

for your problem this first block is better in each case:

```
<div class='popup'>
  <div class='content' style='overflow:auto; width:800px;height:400px;'>
    <div id="C1">
      <span class="Heading">Title 1 come here</span><br/>text for title 1 will come here.</span>
    </div>
    <div id="C2">
      <span class="Heading">Title 2 come here</span><br/>text for title 2 will come here.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if you want to goTo element you need to add #in the href as Curl said : 
your links :

```
<div class='container' align="right">
      <!-- return false; only to do it better -->
      <a href='#C1' class='Link'>Help 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class='container' align="right">
      <a href='#C2' class='Link'>Help 2</a>  
    </div>
```

maybe it doesn't work because of popup is on the top or the bottom of `<body>` and don't scroll when you call it, so I propose the second solution to have a great popup :

---

NEXT PART IS FOR HIDE PART YOU DON'T WANT
your links :

```
    <div class='container' align="right">
      <!-- return false; only to do it better -->
      <a href='return false;' data-open="C1"  class='Link'>Help 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class='container' align="right">
      <a href='return false;' data-open="C2" class='Link'>Help 2</a>  
    </div>
```

and finally change in you javascript:

```
$('.Link').click(function(){
  overlay.show();
  var id = $(this).attr("data-open"); // get ID to show
  $('.popup div').hide(); // hide other
  $("#"+id).show(); // show all div with ID in data-open
  overlay.appendTo(document.body);
  $('.popup').show();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response, but this is not giving desired result.

Comment: ho ?  if the first part do not giving desired result I don't know how to do it better :/ maybe it's because it is in a popup and you popup is at the top (or bottom) of your `<body>` and is poped out after

Comment: I again tested your code in separate test page but it doesn't open popup.

Comment: with the second option ? or the first ? did you add all <script> ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qdfET/ Here is fiddle of my original code. please check once so you can advise me properly.